# How to code "over certain time" in python?

Tags: python

Hey I m trying to program a senor that reads high(1) when someone pass by it.
At the end it should print amount of people passes by it each day(at the end of the day)
this is my pseudo code

```
FOR (sensor output 1 over a day)
count += 1

print count
```

Few thing that I want to clarify, is for statement suitable for the task.
and does python have library or anything which does "over a day"?
thank you

Comment: Which commands are suitable depends on the data structure you have and did not show us.

Comment: What sort of setup are you using? To detect when a day passes, you can simply use the `time` module. What sort of function are you using for your sensor?

Comment: If you store each unique event along with a timestamp into a file or database, you can simply query on time ranges. No need for a loop since a database would handle that for you

Answer (score 1):

```py
import time
initial_time = time.time()
```

So something like

```py
while time.time() - initial_time < 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000:
    #execute code
```

should work

Comment: BTW, rename `time` variable to something else like `time_begin`. Because now your `time` variable has same name as `time` module. You code will not work and will throw error, you can try to run it and you'll see.

Comment: Yeah sorry I approved an edit by mistake. The initial one also had a problem. I'll change it.